# deviseでtwitterログイン機能を実装するにあたりpassword_required?のメソッドで躓いてます。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, devise

ruby 2.2.2p95
Rails 4.2.5
mac yosemite

---

deviseでtwitterログインの機能を実装しております。

以下のページを参考にTwitter認証時はパスワードを要求しないようにpassword_required?というメソッドを作りました。
http://qiita.com/cigalecigales/items/a98be8416bf169ce5942

ただ、twitterの認証は成功するものの、いつもパスワードの入力欄が表示されており困っております。

binding.pryで確認したところtrueになっているのが原因かと思います。

```
[1] pry(#)> super
=> true

[8] pry(#)> super.class
=> TrueClass
```

しかし、このsuperが何をしているのかが、今の私の知識量ではわからず、
deviseのソースコードを読んでみたり、ググッてもわからなかったため質問させて頂きました。

宜しくお願いします。

※twitter連携機能自体は実装されており、上手く連携されております。
連携時はパスワード欄を隠したいというところだけが上手く行ってません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qiitaに載っているコードは以下のようになっています。

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # (省略)...
    def password_required?
        super && provider.blank?
    end
end
```

`password_required?`メソッドの実装はおそらく、

- 親クラスのルールにおいてパスワード入力が必須（super）
- かつ（&&）、providerが未指定（provider.blank?）
- であれば、パスワード入力を必須とする

という意味だと思います。

> このsuperが何をしているのかが、今の私の知識量ではわからず

superは親クラスの同名メソッド（つまりpassword_required?）を呼びだしています。
具体的にはDeviseの中で実装されているメソッドです。

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb#L50

```
  # Checks whether a password is needed or not. For validations only.
  # Passwords are always required if it's a new record, or if the password
  # or confirmation are being set somewhere.
  def password_required?
    !persisted? || !password.nil? || !password_confirmation.nil?
  end
```

コメントにもあるとおり、

- モデルがDBにまだ保存されていない
- または、パスワードか確認用パスワードがセットされている

状態であればパスワード入力が必須になります。

> twitterの認証は成功するものの、いつもパスワードの入力欄が表示されており困っております。
>   binding.pryで確認したところ（superが）trueになっているのが原因かと思います。

初回ログイン時は「モデルがDBにまだ保存されていない」状態なので super は必ずtrueになります。（つまり原因ではない）
原因は「providerが未指定」になっている方だと思います。

フォームを表示する前に、Userモデルのproviderに "twitter" のような値をセットすれば provider.blank? は false になり、結果として password_required? も false になるはずです。

ただ、Qiitaの記事にはどのタイミングでどんなコードを使ってproviderをセットするのか書かれていないので、自分で考えて実装する必要がありますね。

Answer (score 0):

Qiita の記事には下記のように記載があります。

> Userのproviderがカラの場合のみPassword入力を要求する。

よって、単にコードの転記ミスであり、実際は、逆ではないのでしょうか？

```
def password_required?
  provider.blank? && super
end
```

他の記事を見ても、super は後に来ているように思います。

[validation - Rails3 devise / omniauth - password_required? and form_for :validate => true don't work together - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846480/rails3-devise-omniauth-password-required-and-form-for-validate-true-don)

```
def password_required?
  (authentications.empty? || !password.blank?) && super
end
```